# Project requires the following components installed on your machine: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base

Tags: google-maps, xamarin

I am developing a cross platform mobile app with Xamarin Forms PCL. There I want to create a screen with Google Map, for that have added NuGet package i.e. Xamarin.Forms.Maps as guided in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/. But after installing this package, my solution stopped working and event I can't clean/rebuild it.

[Click here to see detailed error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV2is.png)

Any suggestion would be great help for me.